# In bash, why are new lines ignored in this case?

Tags: bash, quotes, cat

I am facing this situation I do not understand.

I have a file containing three lines. When I just `cat` it, it returns the following:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

However, when I assign the cat return to a variable like so:

```
tmp=$(cat myfile )
```

And echo its content:

```
echo $tmp
```

It gives the following:

```
line1line2line3
```

Why does it behave like this ?

Comment: Use `echo "$tmp"` to preserve newlines, spaces, tabs ...

Comment: It does. But my situation is a bit more complexe. The cat is sent through a pipe. `VAR=$(cat ../tmp/offset_tmp |  dosomething)`. How should I proceed in this case ? @Socowi

Comment: Proceed like Cyrus suggested. The pipe is irrelevant. Your variable contains the correct value, but that value gets mangled if you write `$tmp` instead of `"$tmp"`.

Comment: You are safe if you always use double quotes when accessing the contents of variables.